# Count all NaNs in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count  NaN  element (data type class 'numpy.float64')in pandas series to know how many are there
which data type is class 'pandas.core.series.Series'

This is for count null value in pandas series

```py
import pandas as pd
oc=pd.read_csv(csv_file)
oc.count("NaN")
```

my expected output of `oc,count("NaN")` to be 7 but it show `'Level NaN must be same as name (None)'`

Comment: `df['col_name'].isna().sum()` ?

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `count` isn't what you want counted (it's actually the axis name or index).

You're looking for `df.isna().values.sum()` (to count NaNs across the entire DataFrame), or `len(df) - df['column'].count()` (to count NaNs in a specific column).

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe looks like this ;

```
aa = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,np.nan],[3,np.nan,5],[8,7,6],
                 [np.nan,np.nan,0]]), columns=['a','b','c'])
    a    b    c
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  3.0  NaN  5.0
2  8.0  7.0  6.0
3  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

To count 'nan' by cols, you can try this

```
aa.isnull().sum()
a    1
b    2
c    1
```

For total count of nan

```
aa.isnull().values.sum()
4
```

Comment: .isnull().values.sum() and .isnull().sum()  what different they have

Comment: `.values` gives a numpy representation, so sum of that will give the total count. Else using just `isnull().sum` shall sum by cols

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following if your `Series.dtype` is `float64`:

```
oc.isin([np.nan]).sum()
oc.isna().sum()
```

If your `Series` is of mixed data-type you can use the following:

```
oc.isin([np.nan, 'NaN']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

`oc.size` : returns total element counts of dataframe including `NaN`
`oc.count().sum()`: return total element counts of dataframe excluding `NaN`

Therefore, another way to count number of `NaN` in dataframe is doing subtraction on them:

```
NaN_count = oc.size - oc.count().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can do either

```
df.isnull().sum().sum()
```

or

```
len(df)*len(df.columns) - len(df.stack())
```

Comment: if there there is more than 25 columns name  it will not show all nan count with respect to columns

Comment: @seeon Remove one sum then you get the nan count for each column.